# ls --group-directories-last ? (List directories AFTER files)

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

We know there is a way to list directories before files using:

```
ls -1 --group-directories-first
```

Is there a way to get the opposite? I thought `--reverse` would do the trick but apparently not.

NOTE: I don't need a solution that works with multiple column output. Hence I've included `-1` (or, analogously, `-l`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of the shell is that you can compose different units of logic using pipes:

```
ls -1 --group-directories-first | tac
```

Where `tac` reverses what it receives from stdin (opposite of `cat`). It even works with colored output which was crucial for me:

```
ls -1 --color=always --group-directories-first | tac
```

Comment: Hmm. On `cygwin` the two commands give different output. `ls --group-directories-first` outputs multiple columns of names. `ls --group-directories-first | tac` outputs a single column of names.

Comment: Sorry, I needto update my answer with the `-l` option

Comment: And the question as well then :)

Comment: Does the output need to be in a single column for this to work? I.e is the `-1` option necessary?