# How to ls --group-directories-last?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

The question is basically the same of [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1106275/ls-group-directories-last-list-directories-after-files), however there are 2 things that I don't like in the accepted answer:

1. it breaks the natural column structure of `ls`;
2. `tac` inverts the order of the output lines, not the order of the output groups (directories should be in the same order within the directory group).

What I'm looking for is something exactly like the option `--group-directories-first`, except with files first.

Comment: About the 2nd thing: add `--reverse`.

Comment: Cool. What can I do for the columns?

Answer (score 0):

What about `ls -l | sort -k 1.1,1.1 -s` ?

Comment: It gets the order correct, but I don't want the long listing format, just the regular `ls` column structure.

Comment: That's better, but it still doesn't work properly. There are two problems: 1) the output of ls has color codes which mess up the alignment of column; 2) to be truly equivalent to the `ls` command it would have to print the same number of columns. A possible way to do this would be to output a regular ls first, count the columns, and then tell `column` to display that many columns. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/dfRLATz) a comparison between `ls` and your command as displayed on my machine.

Comment: You are right. The coloring messes up the alignment because `column` interprets it wrong. I did not see that because my terminal is not colored and I also don‘t know a way around that, apart from disabling the colorization. Sorry. It also fails if the files have spaces on their names. For that at least I can offer a solution: `ls -lnp --color=never | sort -k 1.1,1.1 -s | sed -e "$ d" | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9- | column`. This SHOULD look exactly like regular `ls -p`, except rearranged. I hope that works better for you.

Comment: Yeah that works but not having colors is not a compromise I'm willing to make. I might just send a feature request to the GNU foundation.